# jQuery actions (in general) not working -Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, dreamweaver

I have been scratching my head on this one and just not quite getting it at the moment.
I am designing a "tab" theme for a new design project I am attempting which can be viewed working correctly here http://jsfiddle.net/a598t/ ... this will be the end result when it is working on anywhere but fiddle ...  This is where I am stuck ...
I have developed the same code as seen in jsfiddle using Dreamweaver and it just will not perform anything from .hide() to .animate({})
I am no expert on jQuery but I know when something makes absolutely no sense.  Could I have somebody look over my shoulder on this and see if I am just blind? Here is my code snippet from dw ...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#billing").click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
        width:100
        });
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#billing, #tracking, #support
{
    width:20px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:black;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="billing"></div>
<div id="tracking"></div>
<div id="support"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This all looks correct to me ... but like I said, no expert ... thanks ... btw I cut out most of the header so it was less code ... thanks for any help you can offer

Comment: Still not going ... Now it has <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> ... I noticed when opening source on Chrome there is added whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this one :)

**`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`**

code working...