# Why isn't Jquery giving the <divs> the collapsed class when the anchors are clicked on?

Tags: html, jquery, dreamweaver

I'm making a login/register webpage and would like to alternate between both when you either click on Register or Login anchors. To do so I'm using Jquery and I cannot figure out the reason why it doesn't run the function. I have organised the login and register with the <div id="register" or id="login". The goal is to use the class called collapsed to not display one of the two. If you need any more info that I have forgotten to add please comment.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("div #register").addClass('collapsed');
    
    $('#form a').click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        $(event.target).parent().parent().parent().addClass('collapsed');
        $(event.target).parent().parent().parent().siblings().removeClass('collapsed');

        document.title = $(event.target).attr('id');
    });
});
```

```css
.collapsed {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
            <div id="register" class="">
                <h2>Register</h2>
                <form action="login_register.php" method="post">
                    <span>Have an account? <a id="Login" class="change" href="#login" >Login</a></span><br>
                    <div id="half-left" class="textbox">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" required autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div id="half-right" class="textbox">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" required autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textbox">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" required autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textbox">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="login" class="">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <form action="login_register.php" method="post">
                    <span>Don't have an account? <a id="Register" class="change" href="#register" >Register</a></span><br>
                    <div class="textbox">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" required autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textbox">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <span class="password">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can u please explain the click function, which one your trying to addclass to on clicking each anchor tag. name them if u can.

Comment: I'm not the best with Jquery, so sorry if I cant explain the best. Im trying to add the collapsed class to its 3rd parent which would work out to be the <div. and then I'm removing the collapsed class from the other <div.

For example, the Login is shown and then someone clicks on "Don't have an account? Register" it would show the Register and hide the Login.

Comment: Have you got a class defined as collapsed? The functions seem to work fine? My only guess is your classes are wrong or not defined. Would help if you included relevant CSS.

Comment: .collapsed {
 display: none;
}

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wLms4jne/ - I've done nothing to your code, and seems to work fine. My guess might be however you're viewing the page your coding? Have you checked your console for any errors?

Comment: hmmm not sure then what is making mine not work, I'm using Dreamweaver, how do I check for errors.

Comment: Don't use dreamweaver to view your live code - oh emm gee. View your page in a proper browser.

Comment: I'm using the preview to browser button. I'm not that much of a buffon.

Comment: Just open it normally. Not via dreamweaver. Dreamweaver is the WORST.

Comment: Ok ok ill try. Still didn't work, the title did change.

Comment: If it works in JSFiddle, it should work. The issue is on your end.

Comment: So what should I check?

Comment: IT WORKS YAY. But I think I will need it to work on Dreamweaver because It might be marked on dreamweaver.

Comment: Your browser console for errors.

Comment: no errors on the browser

Comment: I've written an answer for you. See if it helps with your Dreamweaver issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery actions (in general) not working -Dreamweaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486242/jquery-actions-in-general-not-working-dreamweaver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed an older version of Jquery for it to work on Dreamweaver.

The code worked fine.

Here is an older version that should work: [jQuery actions (in general) not working -Dreamweaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486242/jquery-actions-in-general-not-working-dreamweaver)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#register").hide();
    
    $('#form a').click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        let id = $(this).attr("id");
        if (id === "Login"){
         $("#login").show();
         $("#register").hide();
        }
        else if(id === "Register"){
          $("#login").hide();
          $("#register").show();
       }
        

        document.title = $(this).attr('id');
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your code but it still seems to not work.

Comment: The error is not with your code.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: see my other comment with link.

Comment: if the class collapsed => .collapsed { display: none; }. Then instead of addclass and removeclass you can just use show() or hide() as well

Comment: I think OP's issue is with his browser, not the code. His browser might be blocking script. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/wLms4jne/

Comment: I've tried every browser available on Dreamweaver

Comment: Don't use dreamweaver as a browser! what the eff friend. Use an ACTUAL browser to view your page.

Comment: try with the code i have updated now. which uses show() and hide() function instead of collapsed class.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have to use proper HTML format, ie; proper use of `<HTML>` and `<head>` etc as Dreamweaver can be pretty particular.

So try change it to something like;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("div #register").addClass('collapsed');
    
    $('#form a').click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        $(event.target).parent().parent().parent().addClass('collapsed');
        $(event.target).parent().parent().parent().siblings().removeClass('collapsed');

        document.title = $(event.target).attr('id');
    });
});
```

```css
.collapsed { display: none; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form">
            <div id="register" class="">
                <h2>Register</h2>
                <form action="login_register.php" method="post">
                    <span>Have an account? <a id="Login" class="change" href="#login" >Login</a></span><br>
                    <div id="half-left" class="textbox">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" required autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div id="half-right" class="textbox">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" required autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textbox">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" required autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textbox">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="login" class="">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <form action="login_register.php" method="post">
                    <span>Don't have an account? <a id="Register" class="change" href="#register" >Register</a></span><br>
                    <div class="textbox">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" required autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textbox">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <span class="password">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Dreamweaver can be VERY particular about proper coding and formatting etc.

Comment: Yeah i have that, I just didn't show that in the code. Sorry that isn't the problem. What else is there to code on?

Comment: If you have to use Dreamweaver, then we should focus on getting that working.

Comment: I've udpated the code. Try again. You'll notice I changed the URL in the ``<script>`` tag slightly.

Comment: That was just a question for what else is there in the future. But yes I need to use Dreamweaver.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> thats mine

Comment: Notepad++ or Visual Studio Code are what I use, and both are free.

Comment: You might have to look into how to get jQuery to work properly in whatever version of Dreamweaver you are using.

Comment: Are there limitations with Dreamweaver with javascript libraries?

Comment: Doing some googling, it appears so. More reason for my distaste in Dreamweaver haha.

Comment: Got it working with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486242/jquery-actions-in-general-not-working-dreamweaver

Comment: For some reason 1.10.2 works but 3.4.1 doesn't hmmm

Comment: Ah, so it appears you have to use an OLD version of jQuery. This makes sense. Dreamweaver is a bit.... yeah.... you'll soon learn why most devs hate it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll close the question now. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Good luck and all the best! However, if you want to keep using newer jQuery, my recommendation is have a REAL browser open (not via Dreamweaver) and use Dreamweaver to make your changes, save it, then refresh your live browser window to see if it works etc :)